# Backup then restore PC 1:1

Tags: windows, backup

I want a program or a method to fully backup PC (registry, all C-drive files), then restore to that point without any new files created or software installed. Now I know windows backup does similar thing, but it keep all newly created files because it thinks they are personal files and must be kept, which is exactly what I don't want. I don't want to keep any personal file or any file/folder at all that has been created after the backup.
So basically TLDR:

1. Backup PC registry + all C-drive files
2. Create files, folders, install drivers, install programs/games etc..
3. Restore PC
4. Now I don't want to see any files, folders, drivers, new registry values, or any programs/games that were previously installed after the backup.

Comment: Just use an backup program that creates an image of your system like Macrium, TrueImage, AOMEI backup...

Comment: It seems you're looking for an imaging program, not a backup one.

Answer (score 1):

Look for "Clonezilla"  It's free and will make an exact copy of your hard drive.  You can use this for entire system snapshots.  When restored, the result will be exactly as it was when the clone was made.

You can also use that copy to move the data to a new hard drive.

Comment: Could you add a link to this in your answer?  I think that would be more helpful so they make sure to land on the proper software page.  Maybe also provide some information about how to use it and the costs of using it?

Comment: I was reluctant to add a link, not knowing how long it would be before they changed it.  Currently it is: https://clonezilla.org/downloads.php